# Firestore snapshot listener gives only last item after internet connection restores

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have registered a snapshot listener like this for getting continuous updates from changes by other devices in Firestore. Below is the code for the snapshot listener registration:

```
collectionReference = getCollectionReference(id);
mRegistrationListener = collectionReference
    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .whereGreaterThan("timestamp", Timestamp.now())
    .addSnapshotListener((snapshots, error) -> {
        if (snapshots != null && snapshots.getDocuments().size() > 0
            && !snapshots.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()) {
                DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshots.getDocuments().get(0);
                updateUi(ds);
        }
    });
```

But when my device goes offline and then connects again, I am only getting the **last** update sent by others. Not all the other missed updates from Firestore.

How can I get all the missed updates while the device is offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the following method call:

```
.whereGreaterThan("timestamp", Timestamp.now())
```

It means that you are trying to get all documents that have a timestamp greater than the time you actually ran the code. So there can be multiple results that can satisfy this query. However, you are getting only one, because of the use of the following line of code:

```
DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshots.getDocuments().get(0);
```

[QuerySnapshot#getDocuments()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#getDocuments()) method, returns a List. When calling `.get(0)`, it means that you only get the object that exists at index 0. If you want to get all documents, the you should use the following line of code:

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots = snapshots.getDocuments();
Log.d("TAG", "Number of documents: " + snapshots.size());
```

Which will print the exact number of documents that satisfy that query.

Comment: Though I had figured it out on my own, checking now you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see only the last updates is probably this part of your query:

```
.whereGreaterThan("timestamp", Timestamp.now())
```

When you reconnect or close and open your app it will show only changes after the current moment. Did you try to put there a fixed TimeStamp just to check if that is not the reason. I belive it is because the realtime listener should show all changes comming from the backend.

Comment: .whereGreaterThan("timestamp", Timestamp.now())
I am using this at the time of registering the listener for my purpose. After that time any changes in db should come.